# Sending .delay() and periodic_task for Celery task functions to different queues

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a code base with several apps each with tasks.py, and have a total of 100 of these functions

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='20'))
def sync_calendar_availability_and_prices(listing_id_list=None, reapply_rules_after_sync=False):
```

Its in the old format of celery periodic task definition but works fine on celery==4.1.

These get executed every so many hours or mins via beat and also I call them ad-hoc in the codebase by using .delay(). I want all the .delay() calls to go into a certain celery queue `manual_call_queue` and periodic beat fired calls for same function to go to `periodic_beat_fired_queue` -- is this an easy 1-2 line config change somewhere at a global level to do this?

I use rabbitmq, celery, django and django-celery-beat

Answer (score 0):

To send periodic tasks to a specific queue, send queue/options arg.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='20'), queue='manual_call_queue', options={'queue': 'periodic_beat_fired_queue'})
def sync_calendar_availability_and_prices(listing_id_list=None, reapply_rules_after_sync=False):
```

`queue='manual_call_queue'` is used when task is invoked with .delay or .apply_async

`options={'queue': 'periodic_beat_fired_queue'}` is used when celery beat invokes task.

Comment: Thanks this is great ChillarAnand, is there a way to automatically do this on ALL tasks that are scanned by celery at start (from the django project) -- I want the same exact two-fold queue for ALL tasks, there should be a way of setting this when the scanning of @periodic_tasks happen right?

Comment: Or perhaps I can write a custom decorator my_periodic_task and inside it do this queue definitions and call periodic_task inside my custom decorator?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. @dowjones123

Comment: is there a way to detect inside the called task function, if it was called via beat or from a non-beat way?